# Meteorite on windows 8.1 with vagrant ( cannot install packages )

Tags: meteor, vagrant, meteorite

I am very new to Linux ( does't even know the basic commands ) i am using https://gist.github.com/gabrieljenik/d926cbb90706d95abdee to setup vagrant on my windows 8.1 machine. i have created my test app and need to install packages like iron router etc.

when i try to execute

```
sudo npm install -g meteorite
```

it throws **error : sudo command not found**

```
mrt add iron-router
```

it throws **error mrt: command not found**

cannot figure out what the problem is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're very new to Linux and Meteor, don't use complicated stuff like Vagrant. Just use Meteor on Windows, with WebStorm. It works out of the box.

Note: `meteorite` has long been deprecated. Start with the official Meteor tutorial, http://meteor.com/try.

1. Install [Meteor for Windows](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Preview-of-Meteor-on-Windows)
2. Install and start [WebStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/)
3. Create a new project, choose type Meteor.js app, then "default".
4. Run -> Run -> Edit configurations
5. Click the `+` to add a new configuration of type Meteor
6. Call it `simple-todos` for clarity (this is optional)
7. Click Run

Notice how Webstorm starts a console within the IDE, which shows the familiar Meteor startup sequence:

```
=> Started proxy.
=> Started MongoDB.
=> Started your app.

=> App running at: http://localhost:3000/
```

If you're prompted for any firewall permissions, make sure to allow all traffic from Node.js.

Now you can edit your app in WebStorm on Windows. Welcome to Meteor!

Comment: Thanks alot Dan for such a detailed answer. Actually i was able to create few  test applications on windows and understand the details of meteor. Now i wanted to develop a full fledge application and got an impression that several stuff is not supported on windwos like iron-router etc. So i was not sure if i should continue on windows or setup the linux environment. Please let me know if it is ok to move on windows becuse that will make my life much easier, and if not then i will have to get into vagrant.

Comment: Pretty much everything works on Windows. The only problem is that updating the app takes longer than on Linux, but that is being fixed at this very moment by Slava and Sashko. So I'd say go ahead with Windows and read more at https://github.com/meteor/windows-preview/issues

Comment: i tried to add iron router on windows but it failed. How to add routing to meteor app on windows ? this command fails on windows meteor add iron:router.  Here are the details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28266117/cannot-add-package-iron-router-for-meteor-on-windows-8-1-pro