# Cannot add package iron router for meteor on windows 8.1 pro

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I installed meteor on windows from http://win.meteor.com/. I was trying to install iron router package for meteor on windows 8.1 by downloading following repositories

```
git clone https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-router.git
```

After downloading i renamed the folder to iron-router. Then i downloaded other repositories

```
git clone https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-page-js-ie-support.git
git clone https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-HTML5-History-API.git
git clone https://github.com/EventedMind/blaze-layout.git
```

updated sub modules using git submodule update –-init for

```
meteor-HTML5-History-API
meteor-page-js-ie-support
```

when i execute **meteor add iron-router** i am getting following error

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with win.meteor.com. As I instructed in [my earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28261124/1269037), please install Meteor for Windows from https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Preview-of-Meteor-on-Windows.

Answer (score -1):

ok after spending a lot of time, finally i was able to setup my meteor environment using vagrant ( still like to know if i can get everything working and can move on to build a full fledge application using pure 100% windows environment )

Now for folks out there who faced the same issue, just follow the steps in link mentioned below ( this really worked for me ). I was able to install iron router and bootstrap and tested bootstrap its working. No file sync issues till now. Routers are working as well. Now i am moving on to start building a full fledge application, if i see any issues further down the road i will updat this post.

https://gist.github.com/gabrieljenik/d926cbb90706d95abdee

Comment: You don't need Vagrant. The problem is you were using win.meteor.com, which is old. I'll get in touch with the author to take it down.

Comment: grrrrrrrrrrrrr. ... Now i even want to down vote my own stupid answer ... Thanks for coming back and correcting me. I saw your earlier post, i thought you are directing me to the win.meteor.com and since i had already installed and created few basic applications ( without iron router  ) and played with it, i did't paid attention that i am using totally wrong thing. Thanks again.